# Problema na Criação de Tabelas

Tags: sql

Estou tentando criar uma tabela, e não consigo encontrar o erro em sua criação:

```
CREATE TABLE Beneficiarios 
(
       Ano year(4), Homens number(4), Mulheres number(4)
  );
```

Comment: isto está  em sql?

Comment: especifique o banco de dados. Mysql, sqlserver, sqlite, postgre, firebase?...

Answer (score 0):

Como não especificou qual [SGDB](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados) está utilizando, e pelo seu script de criação da tabela `beneficiarios` estar utilizando o `datatype` [year](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/year.html), presumo que está utilizando [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) (ou [sqllite](/questions/tagged/sqllite)), dessa forma o problema do seu script é ter utilizado o `datatype` `number`, que entre os SGDBs é mais utilizado em `oracle`.

Dessa forma troque o `datatype` `number`, por `int`, ficando dessa forma:

```
CREATE TABLE beneficiarios 
(
   ano year(4), 
   homens int(4), 
   mulheres int(4)
  );
```

Fiz um teste utilizando o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e346be).